# How do I change permissions amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2

> How do I change permissions to **make directory in amazon ec2** html folder.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Amazon EC2. Instead, you are interacting with the **operating system** that you selected when the EC2 instance was launched.

Both Windows and Linux have a `mkdir` command that will create directories.

If you are using Linux, you can prefix commands with `sudo` to elevate your permissions. So, you could use: `sudo mkdir /var/www/html`